# JavaFX login system with mysql workbench

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, javafx, mysql-workbench

I'm completely new to java and mysql and I am struggeling with something.
For a project I am working on I want to create a login system where a managers and employees can login.

In the mysql workbench table I have a couple of columns which i need to use to login. The columns are: username, password and function.

So far I have created a login system where a managers or employees can enter his or her username and password and they can login. This works fine.

But now I want to make it so that my code will check if the function is equal to 0 or to 1. If the function is equal to 0 you will login as a employee and if the function is equal to 1 you will login as manager. The difference between the manager and the employee login is that I want the manager to login to a scene called ManagerHomeMenu, and the employee to login to EmployeeHomeMenu.

But as I have stated above, I am completely new to this and I have no clue of what I should do to make this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

CODE:

Database connection:

```
package databasetesten.connection;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Matt Holland
 */

public class ConnectionUtil {

Connection conn = null;

public static Connection connectdb() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mhhproject.nl:3306/Management", "root", "root");
        return conn;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Login applicatie:

```
package databasetesten;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Matt Holland
 */
public class LoginApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FXMLDocument.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="437.0" prefWidth="548.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" fx:controller="databasetesten.FXMLDocumentController">
<children>
<Button fx:id="button" layoutX="204.0" layoutY="162.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Login" />
<Label fx:id="label" layoutX="204.0" layoutY="269.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="149.0" />
<TextField fx:id="textEmail" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="65.0" />
<Label layoutX="107.0" layoutY="69.0" text="Username" />
<Label layoutX="107.0" layoutY="119.0" text="Password" />
<PasswordField fx:id="textPassword" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="115.0" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLMenuEmployee:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" `xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">`

</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLMenuManager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLDocumentController:

```
package databasetesten;

import databasetesten.connection.ConnectionUtil;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Matt Holland
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField textEmail;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField textPassword;

    Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
    Scene scene;

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public FXMLDocumentController() {
        connection = ConnectionUtil.connectdb();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        String email = textEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = textPassword.getText().toString();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE username = ? and password = ?";

        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, email);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (!resultSet.next()) {
                infoBox("Enter Correct Email and Password", "Failed", null);
            } else {
                infoBox("Login Successfull", "Success", null);
                Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
                dialogStage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
                dialogStage.close();
                scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLMenuEmployee.fxml")));
                dialogStage.setScene(scene);
                dialogStage.show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String titleBar, String headerMessage) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle(titleBar);
        alert.setHeaderText(headerMessage);
        alert.setContentText(infoMessage);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }
}
```

This database table looks like this:

```
The database table called employee looks like this:
username      password       function
Bob1          Welcome123     0
Ben1          Bensw123       1
```

Comment: `String sql = "SELECT function FROM Employee WHERE username = ? and password = ?"; ... scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(resultSet.getInt(1) == 0 ? "FXMLMenuEmployee.fxml" : "FXMLMenuManager.fxml")));` ??? Also make sure you properly close the statement. Furthermore there is no point in using a field instead of a variable for the resultset/statement.

Comment: Hello Fabian! I tried your code and it almost works. The problem is now everytime I login as employee and as a manager it logs me in as a manager. I am not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by triggering an event on `login button` click, which will run the function you mentioned. The function can check if provided user is `manger` or `employee` and based on this (simple if-else statement) can load proper scene.

This resource can guide you through it: http://www.javafxtutorials.com/tutorials/switching-to-different-screens-in-javafx-and-fxml/